# How to create Azure VM with ipConfiguration that contains multiple private IP address using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create a VM with two private IP addresses (primary/secondary).  I have a working ARM template that will create the primary, but I don't see where to specify the secondary.

```
"ipConfigurations": [
    {
       "name": "ipconfig1",
       "properties": {
       "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
       "privateIPAddress":  "10.10.100.4",
       "subnet": { 
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'myVnet, 'mySubnet')]" 
       }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ipConfigurations is an array, so you can add another member (or more) to it:

```
"ipConfigurations": [
    {
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
    },
    ...
    {
        ...
    }
]
```